# How to message or mail to teacher for making a appointment?

Tags: phrase-requests

I need to send a message to my teacher for asking an appointment.
But I don't know how to. He is gonna check my homework tomorrow and he wants a message.

**> 先生こんにちは。 作文をチェックのために７日に予約したいです。 よろしくお願いいたします。**

Do you think this is okey? Or what should I add?

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your first question here on the Japanese Language Stack Exchange! Because this website is not a free translation service, we prefer that users show some indication of research effort (e.g. what you think the translation would be); see [japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty good if that's your first email like this! Your teacher would definitely understand you.

Generally in a formal email, there's a set structure we go by. We first put the name of the recipient, followed by a greeting, which you have done. We would then generally say who the email is from. Something like:

> ○○先生
>
> こんにちは。
>   ○○クラスの○○です。

Make sure to replace the ○○s with your teacher's name, what class you are, and your name.

For the body of the email, we generally start out by first saying what the email is about, followed by your request. Introducing the main topic of the email is generally accomplished using「〜(について/の件)ですが、」 in some form or other. This is then connected to the rest of your email body. Also, here,予約 is not necessarily wrong, but it sounds a bit impersonal. It may be better to ask if your 先生のご都合がいい (if they're available) on the 7th. Which happens to be tomorrow. So something like:

> 作文のチェックに関してですが、
>   先生は明日、ご都合のよろしい時間帯は
>   ありますでしょうか。

About the homework check,
Tomorrow, is there a time range you're available?

Then we might finish up by apologizing for disturbing your 先生 with this email, and finally end with よろしくお願いいたします.

In total (assuming your teacher knows about the check you reference):

> ○○先生
>
> こんにちは。
>   ○○クラスの○○です。
>
> 作文のチェックに関してですが、
>   先生は明日、ご都合のよろしい時間帯は
>   ありますでしょうか。
>
> お忙しいところご迷惑をおかけしますが、
>   よろしくお願いいたします。
>
> Your name